# reshape 3d array by flatten the third dimension

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I have this (64, 2, 1) array:

```
[[[-0.93052584]
  [-0.91981804]]

 [[-1.0216997 ]
  [-1.1389164 ]]

 [[-1.0271937 ]
  [-0.8308667 ]]]
```

I don't know how to reshape it to be (64, 2)

Comment: `array.reshape(64, 2)`? `array.squeeze()`?